# How to store mysql row into private array variable?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, web-services, rest

i have a private array variable

```
private $univ = array( 
         1=> "a",
         2=> "b"
        );
```

how to store mysql row into the array

this is the table structure

```
|id|univ   |
|--|-------|
|1 |harvard|
|2 |ucla   |
```

Comment: What have you tried that's not worked?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use cursor object,run the required query,and convert the result into a dictionary with keys as you require.Read the dictionary and push the same onto your array.Let me know if you need code for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Class A {

 private $univ;

 function setUniv(){
  //Get data from the data base into $res variable and then set it
  $this->univ = $res
 }    
}
```

Now where you create the object of class A you can call the set function to set the univ variable 
OR in the same class A, you can define the constructor function and call the setUniv() function in it to set the class property